# For unpublished works print 'pubstate' field in parentheses for in-text citations and bibliography

Tags: biblatex, citing, archaeologie

For my company I'm adapting the `biblatex` style `archaeologie`. Everything works fine, except for one thing:

The standard inline/footnote citation style is *author-year* without parentheses. But for unpublished works I need parentheses surrounding the output of the `pubstate` field – both for in-text citations, as well as inside the bibliography.

For the bibliography this was easy to establish, using `DeclareFieldFormat`, but I can't get it to work with in-text citations. I searched my way through the `cbx` and `bbx` files, as well as the very detailed documentation. As far as I could follow, I need to redefine `\printlabeldateextra` of bibmacro `cite:labeldate+extradate`, but so far wasn't able to get the definition right.

I still have the feeling that I'm missing something very obvious...

My MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\usepackage[%
backend=biber,
style=archaeologie,
]{biblatex}
\renewcommand{\finentrypunct}{\adddot}

\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{testbib.bib}
  @Article{testentry,
  author   = {Guy, Some},
  journal  = {Some Journal},
  title    = {A Title},
  pubstate = {submitted},
}
  @article{testentry2,
  author = {Doubtfire, Mrs.},
  journal = {Another Journal},
  title = {What a title?},
  year = {2000},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\addbibresource{testbib.bib}

\DeclareFieldFormat{pubstate}{\ifbibstring{#1}{\bibstring[\mkbibparens]{#1}}{\mkbibparens{#1}}}

\begin{document}

\cite{testentry}

\cite{testentry2}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image: citations]

In the bibliography, **(submitted)** is correctly enclosed by parentheses. In the text it is still **Guy submitted**, but I need **Guy (submitted)**. The other citation should, of course, print the year without parentheses, as it does in the MWE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can modify the `labeldate` field format to print parentheses if the `labeldate` comes from `pubstate`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[%
backend=biber,
style=archaeologie,
]{biblatex}
\renewcommand{\finentrypunct}{\adddot}

\DeclareFieldFormat{labeldate}{%
  \iffieldequalstr{labeldatesource}{pubstate}
    {\mkbibparens{#1}}
    {#1}}

\DeclareFieldFormat{pubstate}{%
  \mkbibparens{%
    \ifbibstring{#1}
      {\bibstring{#1}}
      {#1}}}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{testentry,
  author   = {Guy, Some},
  journal  = {Some Journal},
  title    = {A Title},
  pubstate = {submitted},
}
@article{testentry2,
  author  = {Doubtfire, Mrs.},
  journal = {Another Journal},
  title   = {What a title?},
  year    = {2000},
}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{testentry}

\cite{testentry2}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Guy (submitted) Doubtfire 2000]

Comment: Aaahh, `labeldatesource` I didn't recognise. Those cbx/bbx/biblatex sources can be confusing sometimes. Seems to be the solution. Will test it at home and mark it as answer then.

Comment: As expected, it did the trick. Thank you. Already wrote a note to my own Latex lexicon ;)

Comment: Happy to add that to the style as an update! https://github.com/LukasCBossert/biblatex-archaeologie/issues/156

Comment: @lukascbossert thats great. Thus, I can remove the adaption from my `.cls` file following the next update of your biblatex style files.

Comment: @lukeflo absolutely. We can continue this in the mentioned github-issue. I am curious about your use of 'archaeologie' - LaTeX in archaeology is (unfortunately) still rather unknown.

Comment: @lukascbossert Would be great to talk a little bit about stuff like that since LaTeX is really almost non-existence in archaeology :)